# How to pass in user input into Custom User Model in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I have a custom user model that I need to add an extra field to. The problem I have is that the information needed is user input from the registration page.
This is the code from the form:

```
team = forms.ChoiceField(choices=teamChoices)
```

This is my user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  username = None
  email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
  USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

  objects = UserManager()
```

I need to add something like this:

```
groups = 'team'
```

But I don't know how I would get that information to my model. My user model is in models.py and my registration form is in forms.py.

This is is my current Register Form but I haven't tested to see if it works yet:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'First Name', 'class': 'form-input'}))
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Last Name', 'class': 'form-input'}))
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Email', 'class': 'form-input'}))
teamChoices = (('red','red'),('green','green'),('blue','blue'),('orange','orange'))
team = forms.ChoiceField(choices=teamChoices)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name','last_name','email','team','password1','password2')
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking. Why do you think you need to put that in the class definition? Surely you need a field, like `email`, which you set when you create the user?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I already set up the email field.  I'm asking how do I pass in inputs from the registration form to the model? Say I have a value team that can be red, green, blue, yellow, orange and the user can select any of them with a dropdown menu and I get the values via method = post in a form. How do I pass those values to my user model?

Comment: I need the value for authentication.

Comment: You do it in exactly the same way as all the other fields. How are you setting the email? Do that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman But how do I retrieve that value from my registration form?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking. You must already be capturing the value of the email field from your registration form and using it to create the user. So why can't you do the same to capture the value of the group or team? Maybe you need to show the code for the registration form and the view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Okay, so I don't think my register form is working but I was looking at the AbstractUser source code and I think the code I need is something like this:  groups = models.CharField(_('team')).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue and I wanted to post it here in case anyone's stuck like I was:

If you extended the UserCreationForm in your forms.py, you need to overload the def save(self, commit=True) method and you need to copy paste everything from the method from the [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/) into that overloaded method and then set your user.field value to your field. For my example, the line looks like this:

```
user.teams = self.cleaned_data['team']
```